# How to stretch text to width of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a really long text and I want this text to stretch to fit my div's width. I found this but I can't change it to appropriate form in my situation http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/887/ I made a function which puts words into div "mytext". Can anyone help?

**Html:**

```
<div id="parentdiv">
  <div id="mytext"></div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
#mytext {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25vmin;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
}

#parentdiv {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4%;
  left: 0%;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: changing this js code to my situation

Comment: I don't see any problems in your code. And I don't see how the code did not meet your purpose

Comment: I can't put this script into my code. I'm new in programming. I want my parent div to establish maximal width and my text (which is too long) to fit in it.

Comment: Why can't you specifiy the text tag to 100%. By doing that it will stretch to whatever the size it's being contained within?

Comment: So I added to parent div "width: 50%" and to #mytext "width: 100%" but my text just breaks and is much longer than 50%.

Comment: `ctx.fillText(text, 0, 100);` Why don't you just change the number to 400?